# Why does selectRange() in JavaFX TextArea sometimes not highlight the selection?

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, selection

I have written the following code in my JavaFX main class:

```
package jfxTest;

import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    private static int selectionIndex = 0;
    private static TextArea textArea;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        System.out.println("Starting JavaFX Window...");
        StackPane rootPane = new StackPane();
        textArea = new TextArea();

        textArea.setText("TEST");
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        createRandomOptions(8);

        textArea.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.UP)) {
                select(selectionIndex <= 0 ? 0 : selectionIndex - 1);
            }
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.DOWN)) {
                String[] lines = textArea.getText().split("\n");
                select(selectionIndex >= lines.length - 1 ? lines.length - 1 : selectionIndex + 1);
            }
        });

        rootPane.getChildren().add(textArea);
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 900, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        System.out.println("Created window.");
        System.out.println("\nNow press up and down keys to navigate:\n"
                + "Notice, that although a new selection is displayed in the console, it is not\n"
                + "highlighted in the window itself. Even a call to getSelectedText() works fine.\n");
    }
    
    /**
     * Creates a bunch of random options in textArea.
     * @param newOptionCount
     */
    private static void createRandomOptions(int newOptionCount) {
        for (int i = 0; i < newOptionCount; i++) {
            textArea.appendText("\nSEL" + (new Random().nextInt(10000)));
        }
    }
    
    private static void select(int newSelectionIndex) {
        String[] lines = textArea.getText().split("\n");
        
        System.out.println("New selection index: " + newSelectionIndex);
        selectionIndex = newSelectionIndex;
        
        // Determine selection indexes
        int selectionStart = 0;
        int selectionEnd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < newSelectionIndex; i++) {
            selectionStart += lines[i].length() + 1;
        }
        selectionEnd = selectionStart + lines[newSelectionIndex].length();
        
        // Does not work. Selection does need to be applied twice by the user to be actually highlighted.
        textArea.selectRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
        
        System.out.println("Selected text: " + textArea.getSelectedText() + "\n");
    }
}
```

I know it looks like a mess and is not exactly clean, but you should get the point.
Now the problem is as follows:
When I navigate in the `TextArea` with the arrow keys (specifically UP and DOWN), the selection only becomes visible, when it is applied twice by the user(only at the very top and bottom), although, a call to `selectRange()` is made everytime.

Why is this? Is it a bug in the JavaFX library, or am I missing something?

I have searched the problem a few times already, but I've found no results yet.
I haven't tested this using AWT Swing yet, but I am quite confident, that it would work fine using it.

My Java is OpenJDK 19 with JavaFX version 19.

Comment: @James_D `ListView` may be a good option I haven't thought about. Could you give me a simple implementation with a few options to select from so I can get an idea of how it works?

Comment: Added example (both of using a `ListView` and of doing this with a `TextArea` as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is never a particularly good idea to add low-level event handling (such as mouse and keyboard event handlers) to high-level UI controls. You always stand the risk of interfering with the built-in functionality of the controls, or of the built-in functionality interfering with your event handlers resulting in not giving you the functionality you want.

In your case, the latter is happening: the `TextArea` already implements changing the selection when keys are pressed. If the arrow keys are pressed with no modifier key, then the selection will be cleared. This default behavior is occurring *after* your key press is invoked, so the default behavior is the behavior you see.

You can see what is happening by adding

```
textArea.selectionProperty().addListener((obs, oldSel, newSel) -> 
    System.out.printf("Selection change: %s -> %s%n", oldSel, newSel)
);
```

Note you can workaround this by adding `event.consume()` to both the `if() { ... }` blocks in your key event handler, but I don't think this is a particularly good solution: the solutions below are better imho.

It looks like you are simply using the wrong control here. If you have a non-editable `TextArea` in which you are regarding each line as a distinct item, then it sounds like you are trying to re-implement a `ListView`, which already implements things like selection of the individual items. You can reimplement your example simple with:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    private ListView<String> listView;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        System.out.println("Starting JavaFX Window...");
        StackPane rootPane = new StackPane();
        listView = new ListView<>();


        listView.getItems().add("TEST");
        createRandomOptions(8);


        rootPane.getChildren().add(listView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 900, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        System.out.println("Created window.");
        System.out.println("\nNow press up and down keys to navigate:\n"
                + "Notice, that although a new selection is displayed in the console, it is not\n"
                + "highlighted in the window itself. Even a call to getSelectedText() works fine.\n");
    }


    /**
     * Creates a bunch of random options in textArea.
     * @param newOptionCount
     */
    private void createRandomOptions(int newOptionCount) {
        for (int i = 0; i < newOptionCount; i++) {
            listView.getItems().add("SEL" + (new Random().nextInt(10000)));
        }
    }

}
```

If you really want to modify what is selected in a text area, use a `TextFormatter` with a filter that modifies the selection. This would looks something like this (though, again, I think this is just reinventing the wheel). Note this also behaves the way you (presumably) want on mouse clicks:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.IndexRange;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    private TextArea textArea;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        System.out.println("Starting JavaFX Window...");
        StackPane rootPane = new StackPane();
        textArea = new TextArea();

        textArea.selectionProperty().addListener((obs, oldSel, newSel) -> System.out.printf("Selection change: %s -> %s%n", oldSel, newSel));

        textArea.setText("TEST");
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        createRandomOptions(8);

        textArea.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(this::modifySelection));

        rootPane.getChildren().add(textArea);
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 900, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        System.out.println("Created window.");
        System.out.println("\nNow press up and down keys to navigate:\n"
                + "Notice, that although a new selection is displayed in the console, it is not\n"
                + "highlighted in the window itself. Even a call to getSelectedText() works fine.\n");
    }
    
    private TextFormatter.Change modifySelection(TextFormatter.Change change) {
        IndexRange selection = change.getSelection();
        String[] lines = change.getControlNewText().split("\n");
        int lineStart = 0 ;
        for (String line : lines) {
            int lineEnd = lineStart + line.length();
            if (lineStart <= selection.getStart() && lineEnd >= selection.getStart()) {
                change.setAnchor(lineStart);
            }
            if (lineStart <= selection.getEnd() && lineEnd >= selection.getEnd()) {
                change.setCaretPosition(lineEnd);
            }
            lineStart += line.length() + 1; // +1 to account for line terminator itself
        }
        return change;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a bunch of random options in textArea.
     * @param newOptionCount
     */
    private void createRandomOptions(int newOptionCount) {
        for (int i = 0; i < newOptionCount; i++) {
            textArea.appendText("\nSEL" + (new Random().nextInt(10000)));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Both versions work flawlessly and without any problems. I'll go with the ListView, since this is a direct implementatuon of what I wanted. Explanation is very detailed as well.